# How to figure out why my system is freezing?

Tags: windows, windows-8, freeze, crash, bsod

My system (a dell xps with core i7 and 16 GB ram and tons of hard drive space) keeps on freezing randomly. It happens sometimes when I put the computer in lock mode (by pressing CRTL-L).
The system doesn't unfreeze, and the only thing to resolve the matter is to reboot.
Also, the computer isn't under heavy load, I checked the system resource usage.
Also, all of the fans work and internal temperatures aren't high. The system is also well ventilated and not on the carpet nor on the ground, and isn't dusty, it only a couple of years old.

I am running windows 8.1 Pro,
I have performed a virus check, used CC cleaner, performed defrag, updated my graphics driver, performed system cleanup, removed unused software and I still can't get the computer to stop freezing.

I opened Windows Event Viewer because I read somewhere online that is a good way to debug why the system is crashing, but I can't seem to figure out what is wrong.

So far I found that the bonjour service and tvnserver had lots of errors in the event viewer, so I decided to uninstall both of these applications (Apple related stuff and tight vnc server), but my system is still freezing. Also, I am not sure if these errors occurred as a result of the system being locked (by locked, I mean by pressing CRTL-L), or they are what caused the system to freeze.

Is there any guidance I can get on this issue? Is there a certain way to use event viewer that will tell me exactly what froze the system? Is there some piece of software I can run before the system freezes and it will record what happened?

Comment: I guess you could boot into safe mode to check this out.

Comment: To rule out hardware: Run Prime95 for 1hr to test CPU. Run Memtest 4hrs to test RAM. Run Furmark 1hr to test GPU. Then we can be sure its software. Then you need to look at the event IDs right before the reboot(code 6008).

Comment: @starbox I mean go into safe mode to see if the error still occurs. If it stops, its a program from startup that may cause the issue. If the problem persists, try refreshing your pc.

Comment: @starbox Doesnt really matter, I ususally use blend. It pushes it so hard on all test types that if it passes any we can be pretty sure its stable.

Comment: K, Prime95 is still running (its been over an hour, and all of the tests have "passed" messages so far. I'll move onto Memtest, are you referring to memtest86 to be specific?

Answer (score 0):

Such crazy freezing of OS can be experienced by the bunch of reasons, but from my experience, I would go the following order:

If you are sure that all drivers are OK, that your OS is properly installed and that it is not some software issue (you can try the @RookieTEC9 advice, as this is the first that you should do - best advice so far)

Before you start additional troubleshooting (if needed), pull out all additional hardware that you have in USB and if it still freeze, here is what you can do on your own if you are at least a little bit skilled with hardware:

1. Check the HDD, which is often the cause for such behavior. Run some factory HDD test to be sure that there is no HDD errors
2. Check the memory. If you have two memory sticks, pull out one and check how your system behaves. If it's freezing, replace with another stick, until you check all. Or you can try to borrow the good stick to try. If it's not freezing any more, than add one by another stick and test and to find the faulty one... or run some memory tests
3. Check the BIOS version, and if there is any newer, flash it
4. The worst solution would be the MB issue, but then you cannot do anything on your own